# sql query using script activity in ADF pipeline

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I have a copy data activity in the ADF pipeline that copies data from blob to sql table.

[image]

I use a script activity in order to create an index using a sql query `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ReportsToPersonnelNbr ON TableName(ReportsToPersonnelNbr)` after creating this table via ADF pipeline.

How do I pass the table name from the previous activity to script activity? This is what I tried which gives me the error:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd select Non Query option, instead of Query.

I don't know how you get there, but I use a for-each activity to do bulk inserts and first I drop the index, then I do the insert and then I recreate the index.

I use this:

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_@{item().TargetSchemaName}_@{item().TargetTableName} ON  @{item().TargetSchemaName}.@{item().TargetTableName};

item() contains the result of every loop iteration (schemaName and tableName)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get the tablename out of the Copy Data activity. But what you can do is use a variable to generate your tablename before the Copy Data activity, and then use that variable in both the Copy Data activity and the Script activity:

Like this:

- Create a Pipeline Variable
- Add a Set Variable activity before the Copy Data activity and use that to do the `tbl@{replace(pipeline().RunId,'-','')}` expression evaluation
- Then use that variable in the Copy Activity as the table name `@variables('yourVariableName')`
- then use that same variable in the Script Activity when you do the index `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Whatever ON @{variables('yourVariableName')}`